# List or array is always empty in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to write simple Stack on Kotlin, but all data containers are always throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. I can't find out what can cause this problem:

```
class StackX(size: Int) {
    private var maxSize: Int = size
    private var stackArray: Array<Long> = arrayOf(maxSize.toLong())
    private var top = -1

    fun push(data: Long) {
        stackArray[++top] = data
    }

    fun pop() : Long {
        return stackArray[top--]
    }

    fun peek() : Long {
        return stackArray[top]
    }

    fun isEmpty() : Boolean {
        return (top == -1)
    }

    fun isFull() : Boolean {
        return (top == maxSize -1)
    }
}
```

Could you please explain me the right patter of arrays declaration in this case? I want just this:

```
int a[] = new int[10];
```

P.S. It's test code, I even doesn't call pop. It throws on push. I'm just trying to understand what's wrong with declaration.

Comment: At the moment you are not checking before you pop, so are you trying to pop from an empty Stack?

Comment: @jrtapsell It's test code, I even doesn't call pop. It throws on push. I'm just trying to understand what's wrong with declaration

Comment: If the List is immutable (array always is) in size so it will not increase in size. Using an list the better is to use add() since it will increase the back array to fit the new elements size.

Comment: Or create the list with the size of size:Int

Comment: The `[ ]` operators call `List.get()` and `List.set()` which assume that you will never try to access an index that doesn't exist.  Your initial List has a size of 0, so calling `get` (or using `[ ]`) will always throw an index out of bounds exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the problem 
`private var stackArray: ArrayList<Long> = arrayListOf()`.
It creates an array which length is 0.

Perhaps, you want something like this
`val stackArray: LongArray = LongArray(size)`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `push()` method.

```
private var stackArray: ArrayList<Long> = arrayListOf() // size = 0
private var top = -1

fun push(data: Long) {
    stackArray[++top] = data // top = 0
}
```

What you're trying to do is to get the `0th` element of an *empty* list.

**Possible fix:**

```
fun push(data: Long) {
    stackArray.add(data)
    ++top
}
```

---

**Updated**.

- Creating an `int` array of the specified size:

  ```
  int[] a = new int[10]; // Java
  val a = IntArray(10)   // Kotlin
  ```

  All elements are initialized to zero.
- Creating a `DataItem` array:

  ```
  DataItem[] b = new DataItem[10];   // Java
  val b = arrayOfNulls<DataItem>(10) // Kotlin
  ```

  All elements are initialized to `null`.

Comment: That's correct, but I forgot to update the code, the problem is with a simple array, like int a[] = new int[10];

Comment: But what if I want some custom type array? Like: 
DataItem a[] = new DataItem[4];

Comment: `val a = arrayOfNulls<DataItem>(4)` - an array of 4 `DataItem` objects, each initialized to `null`